# How to avoid updating slug while editing category in symfony2 sonata admin bundle and what is the best practice?

Tags: symfony, slug, sonata-admin

Here I want to know about the best practice first.

Assume we create a category using symfony2 sonata admin bundle then it creates  the slug as well

e.g. Name: "My Category"
     Slug: "my-category"

Now when I edit Category name to "My Category Edited" the slug becomes "my-category-edited".

So first question

Is it good to change slug every time we edit something?
As that slug can be used to put a check say in some if() condition so changing the slug may break things.

My Second Question

How to avoid changing the slug on every edit? I am using Gedmo (http://gediminasm.org/article/sluggable-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2)

Comment: I would love to give more details if not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generally, it's better to keep initial slug in order to avoid 404 not found error (if you use slug as a page identifier).
2. Check "*Some other configuration options for slug annotation*" paragraph in the manual that you provided.

Comment: Thanks Vadim. How can I miss this in docs and I agree with #1 above.